# mysqli large amount of connections

Tags: mysql, php, mysqli

I run a php site with mysqli. I got 3551496 Connections, but there were only 30 processes

1. How can It be
2. What should I do about it?
3. The server is up for 6 month, The problem is that I keep getting too many connections error

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **1) How can it be?**

If you check the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connections) for server status variables, this number (3551496) is:

> The number of connection attempts (successful or not) to the MySQL
>   server.

i.e. the number of connections (plus attempts to connect) since the server was booted!

The number of **active** connections can be verified by looking at the [Threads_connected](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Threads_connected) variable, which gives you:

> The number of currently open connections.

(which is at the bottom of your image and is 29!)

The show [processlist](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-processlist.html) command gives you more information about your **active** connections!

You need to make sure that you're using a privileged user:

> Like the output from the corresponding SHOW statement, the PROCESSLIST
>   table will only show information about your own threads, unless you
>   have the PROCESS privilege, in which case you will see information
>   about other threads, too. As an anonymous user, you cannot see any
>   rows at all.

You will find more relevant information here - the [processlist](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/processlist-table.html) table!

- **2) What should I do about it?**

Congratulate yourself on a site which appears to be running nicely! :-)

Comment: This is the only active connection I have (For all users) , What is the other 3,000,000 connections?

Comment: How long has the MySQL server been up? People are connecting and disconnecting all the time - this is **good** - at that time, you had 29. I don't know your site, but it looks like you've got significant traffic - yes? There are 31,000,000 seconds in a year, so (approx. 1 connection per second for a month or 1 every 10 seconds for a year). Don't know your usage patterns, but IMHO, you've nothing to worry about, as I wrote at the end of my answer! :-). If you're running Linux, use `uptime` or `w` find how long your Linux/Unix machine has been up. Run `mysql status`for the actual db uptime!

Comment: The server is up for 6 month, The problem is that I keep getting too many connections error

Comment: I would suggest that this depends on your system's RAM, CPU and HDD configuration! You have Max_used_connections = 74 (not huge), but your graphic doens't have [Max_connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/too-many-connections.html). Is it possible that this value is set too low? If I've answered the first question correctly, could you mark it as such? You could always ask a second question with a link back to this one (and comment with  @Vérace in the text here so I know where to look). In a word, check your value of  Max_connections!

Answer (score 0):

3.5M Connections in 6 months is fine.  In fact, it is below average.  If it gets to about 1 per second, you might begin to look into it.

"Too many connections" only happens when `max_connections` is exceeded.  `Max_used_connections` says that there were 74 at some point in the last 6 months.  Is that more than `max_connections`?  If not, then I don't understand the problem -- can you provide the exact text of the error.

It might also be useful to see `SHOW VARIABLES` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`.  (At least 3 things of interest are missing in what little you showed; maybe more.)  While you are at it, how much RAM do you have and what version are you running?

Except for the spike of "74", I am with Vérace in saying "NP".

Comment: max_connect_errors:100
max_connections:350
15 GB RAM